# Generating view and stored procedure scripts

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Is there any table in SQL Server that actually stores the metadata of views and stored procedure?

I.e. their actual scripts.

Any knowledge would be very helpful

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the scripts are retrieved like this:

```
SELECT name, object_definition(object_id) AS script
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type_desc IN ('SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION',
    'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE',
    'SQL_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION',
    'SQL_TRIGGER',
    'VIEW')
```

Comment: You can also use `sys.procedures` and `sys.views` for easier access (no more need to specify the elusive `type` in your queries....)

Answer (score 0):

`sp_helptext` is your friend

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176112.aspx

(xxx)